# How much memory I would need for something like this?

Tags: php, image

If I create social portal similar to Twitter (not exactly twitter, but similar in my country), how much space would I need for images? I guess with 100 gb of disk space it won't be enough, so could you please give me some information how much I would exactly need? And is there any suggestions how should I add the profile images? Is there any tactics from programming side, when I could save some space uploading and hosting images for profile users? I guess, each time user changes images, it would be good to delete the previous image, correctly?

In additional, how much disk space would be needed for 1000000 user profiles, if we have like 15 default images, and part of the users won't upload their own images, but use some of the default ones.

So 3 questions -

1. How much disk space I would need to hold a good social portal?
2. Is there any suggested way to deal with pictures with PHP to save disk space?
3. How much disk space would be needed for 1000000 user profile, if we have like 15 default images and part of the users won't upload their own, but instead use one of the 15 default images?

EDIT: I'm about to launch the site on a BETA test.

Comment: I think this question is too broad - too many issues to answer in a single question. But I'd advise that you are 'learning to run before you can walk' - it's probably too early to be thinking about this stuff. Build something first on a 5GB server, and see if you can get people to use it; that is a tough challenge in itself. Make it rough-and-ready, and do it quickly, since you'll likely find it will need to change quite a bit before you will need to scale.

Comment: There is no specific answer to this question. There just too much variables like "how big are your images".

Comment: I'm almost finished and about to launch it on a BETA test, currently I have 100 gb server, that runs 5 websites (85 gb left free). Sure, I will see how it will go on, how fast people will join this project e.c., I have a plenty of ideas ( new cool ideas, that twitter don't have, but I'm not sure if I will be able to realise them, since I will need help from big companies, like google e.c. ). The images, are profile images, not sure, how big, but I guess between 0.5 - 1.5 mb's. I will need to specify some imaage max size, so gonna check for some more information.

Comment: Ah, you're in beta already. Edit your question and mention that `:)`

Comment: For (thumb-sized) profile images: Gravatar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How much disk space I would need to hold a good social portal?

Impossible to say. I would choose a hosting which is able to scale when needed. This way you don't have to worry about it right now.

> Is there any suggested way to deal with pictures with PHP to save disk space?

Save a hash of the images somewhere and if somebody uploads a new image check this against the hash of already added images. So you won't have dupes.

> How much disk space would be needed for 1000000 user profile, if we have like 15 default images and part of the users won't upload their own, but instead use one of the 15 default images?

Again: impossible to say.

The bottom line is disk space isn't really expensive (as long as there isn't any disaster involving water coming up in the countries where disks are being made). As long as you can scale you shouldn't have to worry about it.

If the site will be a real success you don't have to worry about costs anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I believe Twitter allows a maximum size of 700 kilobytes for avatars. Now, if we assume (and it's probably a big assumption), that 90% of your 1,000,000 users opt for a personal avatar, that's 900,000 different 700 kilobyte images. That's 630,000,000 kilobytes in total. That's 600.81 gigabytes.

Obviously the answer entirely depends on the size of the images you're using and what percentage of the users opt for personal avatars, although hopefully the above will give you an idea.

You can work it out yourself:

```
// Get required size in gigabytes
$size_in_kb_of_avatar * $number_of_personal_avatars / 1048576
```